# Creating an array from substrings in Bash not working

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split, truncate

Why are the last two array elements being truncated?

I'm trying to generate an array from a string in bash, using a \n as the delaminating character. Using command substitution and `tr` I was close to what I wanted, now I'm getting strange output.

Script file below

input string: `abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
oper () {
        local fct=$1
        local s=$2
        IFS='\n' read -ra sArr <<< "$s"
        for item in ${sArr[@]}
        do
                printf "   %s\n" $(echo $item | rev)
        done
}
echo "original string: $2"
oper $1 $2
printf "mirror string: "
exit 0
```

Here's the output

```
original string: abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop
   dcba
   hgfe
   lkji
   m
   po
```

Comment: "[delaminating](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/delaminating)" - it's usually called a [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

> Why are the last two array elements being truncated?

Because **any** character in `IFS` causes splitting into words, not both. Seeting `IFS='\n'` splits the input string on `\` **or** `n`. Because `mnop` has an `n` in it, it is splitted to `m` and `op`.

First change the sequence of `\n` character to something that is a single character and uniq - then you may use `IFS=.. read`. For example:

```
IFS='!' read -r -a sarr < <(sed 's/\\n/!/g' <<<"$s")
```

Remember to check you script with http://shellcheck.net to correct quoting problems.